# What are the advantages of having customized commands with the <Leader> key on Vim?

Tags: vim, command, key

I think its self explanatory. How it is more efficient to use that key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious advantage is whenever you decide to change combinations you could easily do it by changing the `mapleader` key.

This can happen when your favorite plugin conflicts your favorite shortcut. By changing `mapleader` you're essentially keeping the shortcut but changing it at the same time.

**Before** (mapleader is `,`)

myFavoriteAction = `,cc`

**After** (mapleader is `\`)

myFavoriteAction = `\cc`